Kalman Filter where we draw a lot of observations from a distribution
I know the classical Kalman Filter update equation
$$
P_{k|k-1} = F_k P_{k-1|k-1} F_k^T + Q_k \\
S_k = H_k P_{k|k-1} H_k^T + R_k \\
K_k = P_{k|k-1}H_k^T S_k^{-1} \\
P_{k|k} = (I - K_k H_k) P_{k|k-1} \\
$$
and its derivation pretty well. It's assuming that we have an observation vector $z_k$, which has a noise $z_k = H x_k + v_k$ where $v_k \sim N(0,R)$. Then we can update our posterior estimation $x_{k|k} = x_{k|k-1} + K_k y$ where $y = z_k - H x_k$
Now I want to have a slightly different setup. Instead of having an observation $z_k$ which follows $z_k = H x_k + v_k$ where $v_k \sim N(0,R)$, I have a lot of observations that draw from $N( z_k, T_k )$, but each observation has noise $R_k$.  $z_k$ and $T_k$ are known. Is there a closed analytical solution to $K_k$ in this case?
I imagine I have to somehow "integrate" over the distribution of $N( z_k, T_k )$ but I am not sure how to approach that... We can even assume $T$ and $R$ are diagonal

Hi: is $x_k$ still around or is that gone in your revised setup ?  It's hard to tell from what you wrote whether you still have a kalman filter or not because a KF has an observation equation for $z_k$ but also a system equation for $x_k$. It's difficult to tell if the system equation is still around in your revised problem.

Hi mark, yes $x_k$ is still the same, it's just that I start to have a lot more observations that follow a distribution.

Hi @Helen Smith. I responded at the bottom to obareey but, unfortunately, I'm still a little confused because, without an observation equation, I'm not certain that having a system equation makes sense. The system equation allows one to update the distribution of $x_k$ based on the measured $z_k$ but, as obareey stated, you no longer have a measured $z_k$.

So you're saying that at each timestep $k$ you have a collection of $N$ $z_{k, n} \sim N(z_k, T_k)$, and a vector of observations $\hat z_{k, n} = z_{k, n} + v_k$, $v_k \sim N(0, R_k)$ -- yes?

You can stack up all the measurements and use the same formulas such as
$$\begin{bmatrix}z_k^{(1)} \\ \vdots \\ z_k^{(N_k)} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}H_k \\ \vdots \\ H_k \end{bmatrix} x_k + \begin{bmatrix}v_k^{(1)} \\ \vdots \\ v_k^{(N_k)} \end{bmatrix} $$
where $N_k$ is the number of measurements for step $k$, $E[v_k v_k^T] = \operatorname{blkdiag}\left\{R_k^{(i)}\right\}$ and $v_k$ is the full noise vector above.
Edit. I assumed all measurements are independent of course.

Thanks. do you think this can be further simplified somehow with $T$? We can even assume $T$ and $R$ are diagonal

I didn't understand your question. If you know $R$, then you also know $T$ since $x$ is deterministic. Am I missing something?

Thanks, I don't actually have the observations. I just know my observations would draw from $N(z_k, T_k)$. Would there be a closed form of $K$ that also depends on $T_k$ such that $x_{k|k} = x_{k|k-1} + K_k y$ ?

If I understand correctly $z_k$ is not measured at all, but has a known distribution, is that right? But the whole premise of Bayesian filtering related methods is to calculate $p(x_k | z_{1:k})$, where $p(\cdot)$ is conditional probability distribution. So, $z_k$ must be measured. However, if you know the joint probability distribution $p(x_k,z_k)$, then you can calculate $p(x_k) = \int p(x_k,z_k) dz_k$. This of course would not be a filter, so there is no $K$.

obareey: As I understood it, $z_k$ just has a known distribution which, as you said, makes having an observation equation un-necessary. But then, if one has no observation equation, I don't see the use of a system equation. I think it becomes a simpler problem but Helen said that she still has the system equation.
